# SSL in iOS - Basic steps

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, ssl-certificate

In my app I am using HTTP connection to communicate between client and server. All is fine. Now I wish to make the connection secure. I am an absolute beginner and I am clueless where I need to start with when it comes to SSL and iOS. I read many of the SO questions. But not able to get a complete clear picture like what I need to do in the iOS app (in Xcode) to make the connection secure.

I have set up a certificate in the server which is issued by the CA for my domain.

Could anyone throw some light on what I need to do at the iOS app end ( whether it is config changes in the XCode or just change the http to https in NSURLconnection or there is something more I need to do). Thanks a lot. This question may sound generic but any info like baby steps will be very helpful for me. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just change your url, NSURLConnection will fail on purpose if it notices a bad certificate and a https url

Comment: Is there some certificate which I need to import in XCode. Can you please give me some links to set this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to get as much info as possible. But I am not able to find the exact information as what I need to do. 
This is what I did and is all fine

1. Purchase the SSL certificate from a SSL Provider
2. Configure SSL in your webserver
3. Change the NSURLConnection HTTP to HTTPS

Thats it. All is working fine now.

Hope this helps some one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could follow this guide from Apple to have a basic understanding of the process using HTTPS, play special attention to the "Configuring Authentication" section, where you will be explained how to trust / verify / connect against your server.
Here is the link, hope this helps !
[HTTP - HTTPS Connections for iOs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH8-SW1)!